# SharePoint Subscription Edition - listdata.svc service not able find lists which have spaces in list name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, listdata.svc

We have a SharePoint Subscription Edition (SE) environment which we have migrated from our SharePoint 2013 environment using DB attach method (SP2013 -> SP2016 -> SE).
We have an application which reads some lists from a site using the `listdata.svc` service. We have noticed that if the list name has spaces in it, `listdata.svc` service throws the following error when accessing the list in SharePoint SE:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-1, System.ArgumentException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">List 'ListName' does not exist at site with URL 'SiteURL'.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

The same request works in our SharePoint 2013 environment, whereas in SE it throws the above error.
For example, for a list with name "Mid Repair Audit", to request it with the listdata.svc service, normally its possible to request it by removing the spaces and using the following URL:

```
<SiteURL>/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MidRepairAudit
```

This works in SharePoint 2013 but throws the above error in SE.

If the list name has no spaces, then we are able to access it using listdata.svc in SharePoint SE as well. For example, for a list with name "Coaching", we are able to access it in SE with the following URL:

```
<SiteURL>/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Coaching
```

Is this a know behaviour difference in listdata.svc in SharePoint SE?
How do we access lists with spaces in list name using the listdata.svc service in SharePoint SE?

Comment: Does encoding the spaces works?

<SiteURL>/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Mid%20Repair%20Audit ?

Comment: No that doesn't work either. Now it shows the error "List 'Mid' does not exist at site with URL 'SiteURL'". So it looks like it only considers the part before the first space i.e. "Mid" in this case.

Comment: Can you find the list if you simple run <SiteURL>/_vti_bin/listdata.svc ?

Comment: Yes I can see the list when I run <SiteURL>/_vti_bin/listdata.svc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had opened a MS support case for this. This has now been confirmed as an issue by the Product Group, and a fix will be developed and is scheduled to be applied in the June 2023 PU.